# Can't subscribe a GMB business to pub/sub push notifications

Tags: google-api

I spent several hours trying to solve this stuff.
I need to subscribe a gmb business to pub/sub push notifications. I was able to send/receive messages via gcloud console. Successfully created a topic and a subscription. The problem is that i need to subscribe gmb accounts , but I'm getting this error:

(had to edit this question, the code is better than images)

The request:

```
PUT https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/102834134483270918765/notifications
{
    "topicName": "projects/probable-pager-194417/topics/fetchReviews",
    "notificationTypes": [
    "NEW_REVIEW", "UPDATED_REVIEW", "GOOGLE_UPDATE"
  ]
}
```

The Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.mybusiness.v4.ValidationError",
        "errorDetails": [
          {
            "code": 3,
            "message": "Invalid topic name provided for subscription. Ensure that the topic exists and is shared with the GMB API service account.",
            "value": "projects/probable-pager-194417/topics/fetchReviews"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include errors & other details in text instead of images.

Comment: @ASR the original answer was edited, thanks. Now you got it better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i found the solution. You need to give Pub/Sub Publisher permission in your topic to this account: 'mybusiness-api-pubsub@system.gserviceaccount.com. Have no idea why.

**Exactly that string

Comment: Just a note: the UI is a bit confusing. I accidentally gave permissions to a subscription at first and not the topic itself.

Comment: @Ricardo Almira I have the same issue. I set pub/sub admin permission. But still showing the same error.